# Eclipse plugin to associate a file extension to the HTML editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a custom file extension (.apg) that I want to associate to the standard Eclipse HTML editor, so when the file is opened, it will be opened in the HTML editor, this is what I have, first I created a content type for the file extension:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
    <content-type
        base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.text"
        file-extensions="apg"
        default-charset="UTF-8"
        id="com.test.my.type"
        name="My Custom Content Type"
        priority="high">
    </content-type>
</extension>
```

And then I used the following extension point to try to associate that content type to the HTML editor:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
    <editorContentTypeBinding
        contentTypeId="com.test.my.type"
        editorId="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource.source">
    </editorContentTypeBinding>
</extension>
```

I searched in the Git repository for the plugin that provides the HTML editor and also checked inside the plugin jar to find the id of the HTML editor, looks like this is it: `org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource.source` but when I try to run the application I get this error in the console:

```
!MESSAGE Plugin com.my.test, extension org.eclipse.ui.editors: Unknown editor with id: org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource.source
```

Comment: Check your Eclipse Application launch configuration. Is the HTML UI plug-in included? Do the selected set of plug-ins Validate without missing dependencies or other problems? Is there anything in the log output before this error message that might be relevant?

Comment: The HTML UI plugin is included in the launch configuration, I also verified it by creating an .html file and it is automatically opened with the HTML editor, there are no other errors in the log, that's the only message I see

Comment: Make sure your launch config is Clearing the Configuration Space whenever you make changes to a plugin.xml contents. It's cached to save a lot of time.

Comment: Looks like the plugin.xml is updated, I can see my content type in the preference page (`Window > Preferences > General > Content types`)

Comment: Have you declared 'org.eclipse.wst.html.ui' as a requirement for your plug-in?

Comment: Yes, the plugin is added as a dependency in the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I just had to make my content type a child of the HTML content type, like this:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
    <content-type
        base-type="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource"
        file-extensions="apg"
        default-charset="UTF-8"
        id="com.test.my.type"
        name="My Custom Content Type"
        priority="high">
    </content-type>
</extension>
```

Then files with my custom .apg file extensions are linked to the HTML editor and are automatically opened in it.